# Higher dimensional version of "a product of two reflections is a rotation"

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, orthogonal-matrices, reflection

In higher dimensions, which orthogonal matrices are a product of two reflections? Is it all of $SO(n)$? In the complex case is it $U(n)$?

Comment: What is your definition of reflection for $n \geq 3$? Do reflections through arbitrary subspaces count, or only reflections through, e.g., hyperplanes?

Comment: Or, is it dictated solely by determinants?

Comment: @Travis My apologies! I forgot to mention. Not hyperplanes - any subspace will do.

Comment: In three dimensions, a reflection through a line _is_ a rotation.

Comment: One reflection will reverse the handedness. A second reflection restores it.